# Что такое замыкания в JS?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Лексическое окружение понятно, а как понять замыкания в JS. Какую функцию она выполняет. Можете в простом примере простыми словами объяснить. Почти все видео-уроки бесполезны. В нижеприведенном коде замыкания какую функцию выполняет?

```js
function person() {
  let name = 'Peter';
  
  return function displayName() {
    console.log(name);
  };
}
let peter = person();
peter(); // 'Peter'
```

Comment: Если с английским дружите то здесь расписано всё очень классно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Замыкание - это возможность внутри функции обращаться к переменным, объявленным не в самой функции, а в одном из содержащих её блоков.

Ещё замыканием можно назвать всё множество таких переменных.

В твоём примере переменная `name` доступна через замыкание.

Comment: Лучше чем целые статьи и видео-уроки.

Answer (score 4):

Замыкание – это функция вместе со всеми внешними переменными, которые ей доступны.
То есть, замыкание – это функция + внешние переменные.
Тем не менее, в JavaScript есть небольшая терминологическая особенность.
Обычно, говоря «замыкание функции», подразумевают не саму эту функцию, а именно внешние переменные.
Иногда говорят «переменная берётся из замыкания». Это означает – из внешнего объекта переменных. (источник: https://learn.javascript.ru/closures)

Comment: Основы JS я там изучала(но не не дошла до Замыкания), потом перешла на Metanit, так как там проще по сравнению с Learn.JS.ru(хотя в Метаните тоже не очень понятно написано тема Замыкания)..

Answer (score 1):

Способ, с помощью которого я навсегда запомнил замыкания — **это сравнение их с рюкзаком**. Когда функция создана и передаётся куда-либо, или возвращается из другой функции, то она носит с собой рюкзак. А в этом рюкзаке хранятся все переменные, которые были в области видимости во время создания этой функции.
(Источник: [https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/я-никогда-не-понимал-замыкания-в-javascript-часть-первая-3c3f02041970](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-3c3f02041970) )